# How to manually backup my game save?

Tags: assassins-creed-rebellion

As I do not use the Facebook backup for the game, I would like to backup my game progress to my desktop PC for safe keeping.

Please can you tell me where the files are and which ones I need to save?

It seems the game is developed using Unity game engine, if that's any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Assassin's Creed Rebellion is a Android/IOS App, I can answer you for Android APPs only.

For backup data (and app) of any app I use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), it have a free and paid version, you will need a Android rooted phone to make use of it.

There is some [instructions here](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-backup-and-restore-app-data-with-or-without-root) to make a backup without root, I didn't tested and can't assure that it works

With Titanium Backup

Open the Titanium Backup App > Go to Backup/Restore > Find The App in the List.

[image]

Touch the App and Click in Backup

[image]

My configured folder to backup is in Download folder at my phone, so check out your backup folder in Titanium Backup configuration, open it and just copy to your computer and the backup is done.

[image: - enter image description here]